# How to draw line plot with multiple lines on Tableau?

Tags: visualization, tableau

[image: I have 4 different measures which I would like all on the same line plot. They have the same scale. I tried dual axis, but it does not work for more than 2 plots.]

I have 4 different measures which I want all on the SAME line plot. They do have the same scale. I tried dual axis but it doesn't work for more than 2 plots.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Measure Values" in your Measures Tab. Pull it in Row, and then under the Measures Marks, pull in all the measures you want to display.